# Endless responses from the server in SignalR Asp.Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I programmed a bit wrong I guess, so when I call hub's func from the client, it makes in endlessly, and I've got endless responses from the server with an interval of about a half of a second. So that's the client's code, I guess the problem is not in it.

```
  <input type="text" id="inputMessage"/>
  <button class="submit" id="sendButton"></button>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 let hubUrl = "/Chat";
const hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(hubUrl)
    .build();


     hubConnection.on("Receive", function (message, userName) {
    //some html stuff, just putting message and userName into divs
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    let userName = "@User.Identity.Name";
    let message = document.getElementById("inputMessage").value; 
    hubConnection.invoke("Send", message, userName);
});

hubConnection.start();
```

And that's my ChatHub:

```
    public class ChatHub : Hub {
    public async Task Send(string message, string username)
    {
        await this.Clients.All.SendAsync("Receive", message, username);
    }
}
```

I debugged my code, and it showed that when it gets into Send(string message, string username), it performs it endlessly.
[That's what I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJXfO.png)
As you can see there are a lot of same responses on the left, but it should be only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in some scripts which I added.

```
<script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/console_runner-079c09a0e3b9ff743e39ee2d5637b9216b3545af0de366d4b9aad9dc87e26bfd.js'></script>

<script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/events_runner-73716630c22bbc8cff4bd0f07b135f00a0bdc5d14629260c3ec49e5606f98fdd.js'></script>

<script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/css_live_reload_init-2c0dc5167d60a5af3ee189d570b1835129687ea2a61bee3513dee3a50c115a77.js'></script>
```

Those ones caused my problem.